# Retrieving inserted IDs from saveAll() in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

Using `saveAll()` to save multiple records in CakePHP, I am able to save them successfully in a table. But the problem arises while retrieving the IDs of those saved rows. `LastInsertID()` returns only a single last ID here. How can I get all the last inserted IDs which I have inserted using `saveAll()`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**afterSave** function is called after each individual save in a saveAll execution, so you could do:
In your AppModel

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    var $inserted_ids = array();

    function afterSave($created) {
        if($created) {
            $this->inserted_ids[] = $this->getInsertID();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can place this code into any model and it should work fine. Then to return the IDs after the saveAll in your controller, you would do so like this:

```
if($this->Post->saveAll($posts)) {
    $post_ids=$this->Post->inserted_ids; //contains insert_ids
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanx Sudhir,i tried this but its throwing an error
Undefined property: AppModel:inserted_ids
in my controller, what can be the reason..??

Comment: @vin.it remove var before $inseted_ids

Comment: @ehtesham: thanx ehtesham.i tried it but its still throwing the same error. any other possibilities..?

Comment: It's cool seeing code copied and pasted from one's own blog in a Stack Overflow answer :D

Comment: yes, it should work fine with atomic option set to true.