# How to delete entries when updating table in cakephp?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp

I have Invoice Model and InvoiceCharge Model. InvoiceCharge is belongsTo Invoice & Invoice hasMany InvoiceCharge. Invoice charges are like products and services those are listed in an invoice.

I am using jQuery to add more lines to add more charges.

Saving invoice and invoice_table work as it should.

But when it comes to edit Invoice I would want a "Remove Line" button (thanks to javascript, it works). When i save the invoice i want to update invoice_charges table with the new values, also i want to delete the entires that are not anymore in the invoice (Because i removed some charges by clicking the "Remove Line" button). I could use ajax function to remove those entries as soon as i clicked the button "remove line"; but i am not okay with that method. I only want to add/remove/update entries when i save invoice.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a new invoice shouldn't be a problem, just do a saveAssociated on the data.  When editing the invoice, start out by saving all the data using a saveAssociated, but while doing the save, figure out the ids of the line items you're currently saving.  You can do something like the below to easily track the ids of all of the new LineItems created during the saveAssociated operation -

[Retrieving inserted IDs from saveAll() in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769543/retrieving-inserted-ids-from-saveall-in-cakephp)

Then, do a deleteAll for all line items whose invoice_id is the id of the invoice you're editing, but whose ids were not in the set of those you want to keep.  This will delete all those old line items that you no longer want.

```
$this->LineItem->deleteAll(array('LineItem.invoice_id' => 1, 'NOT' => array('LineItem.id' => array(1, 2, 3, etc.,));
```

Since this method takes multiple database calls to save an invoice, you should do it in a transaction.